# How to edit target_link_libraries

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use boost package in Eclipse platform.
In this line of code:

```
boost::this_thread::disable_interruption di;
```

Although boost-1.41.0-17 is installed and I have included boost/thread.hpp in the code, I receive the this error:

> undefined reference to
> 'boost::this_thread::disable_interruption::disable_interruption()

I'm using CentOS 6 and gcc compiler. Anyone knows what's causing this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62287/how-to-edit-target_link_libraries/) by [modaei](https://answers.ros.org/users/4837/modaei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The boost::thread library is one of the boost libraries that is not contained only in header-files.  Some of the boost::thread code also resides in binary library files that are installed on the system with the rest of the boost installation.

The error message you're getting indicates that the linker is unable to find the implementation code for the disable_interruption() method.  It's probably located in the binary boost::thread library file, so you'll need to tell the linker to also link this library in with the rest of your project.

For ROS, this linking is typically configured in the package's `CMakeLists.txt` file.  The exact call you'll use is different depending on whether you're using rosbuild or catkin:

- For [rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbuild/CMakeLists#rosbuild_link_boost), you can add `rosbuild_link_boost(my_exe thread)`
- For [catkin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#Boost), you can add `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread)` followed by `target_link_libraries(my_exe ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`

If you're able to build your package from the command line, but are only having problems within Eclipse, then the problem may be related to your Eclipse configuration.  See [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#Eclipse) for the recommended steps to configure and run Eclipse with ROS.

**Edit:** fix reference to `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`, thanks to @"Dirk Thomas"

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-05-09**:
For CMake (catkin) the variable is ${Boost_LIBRARIES} - not the short name stated in the answer,

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-08-02**:
What if I only want to link thread lib?